# Why can't I write from the beginning of the box when i modify input text size?

Tags: html

Why can't I write from the beginning of the box when i modify input text size? ?
That s my code:

`<input type="text" style="width:600px; height:300px;" value="" placeholder="Introdu textul tau:">`

Answer (score 1):

Use **textarea** instead of input.

```html
<textarea style="width:600px; height:300px;" placeholder="Introdu textul tau:"></textarea>
```

Comment: Already tried this but I wanted to change the input field from the form. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

By "beggining of box" you meaning corner "0,0"?
You have to use padding to do the trick since vertical-align doesn't work on text inputs.

```
padding-bottom: 250px;
```